# Determining a Complex Matrix Given A^2

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers

Find a matrix A ∈ M2×2(C) such that A^2 =

\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}

Do I basically figure out what two complex numbers multiplied together result in each of the entries in the A^2 matrix? For example, i*i=-1, which would mean the bottom right entry for the A matrix is i? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Serious question: do you know how to multiply matrices? And you know that $A^2$ is just $A$ matrix-multiplied by $A$?

Comment: @GitGud, Sweet, I was able to figure out the matrix A. There is a second part to the question: Why can we not find a matrix A ∈ M2×2(R) for A^2?

Comment: @GitGud, Would it be because you can't multiply two of the same number to get a -1?

Comment: @JenniferHall Yes, that is correct.

Comment: You can use MathJax for inline math, too: for example, to be fancy, you could change `A ∈ M2×2(C)` to `$\boldsymbol{A}\in\mathcal{M}_{2\times2}(\Bbb{C})$` which returns $\boldsymbol{A}\in\mathcal{M}_{2\times2}(\Bbb{C})$!